# Pandas drop row santax issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have a basic question.

My code is as such:

```
data1.loc[remove_date].iloc[[1]]
```

This produces a row and i want to drop that row `inplace` but i am not sure exactly where to put `.drop(inplace =True)`
As per @Hamza usman ghani's suggestion:

```
indexes = data1.loc[remove_date].iloc[[1]].index
```

and tried to convert indexes to string
data1.drop(data1.index[indexes.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')], axis = 0,inplace =True)
still produces `IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer or boolean type` Could the reason for this error be that it is finding 2 rows with the same date since `indexes` is just a date and not the first row of the 2 same dates?
Any help would be helpful.

`data1.loc[remove_date]`
produces

```
    High    Low     Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close
Date                        
2021-03-28  56610.312500    55071.113281    55974.941406    55950.746094    47686580918     55950.746094
2021-03-28  58342.097656    55139.339844    55947.898438    57750.199219    57625587027     57750.199219
```

Thats why i want to drop `data1.loc[remove_date].iloc[[1]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.index[]` and pass indexes of your data you wants to delete:

```
indexes = data1.loc[remove_date].iloc[[1]].index
data1.drop(data1.index[indexes],inplace =True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That made sense to me however i am now getting `IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer or boolean type`. Any thoughts?

Comment: What did you get in indexes ?

Comment: indexes is `datetime`. `DatetimeIndex(['2021-03-28'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)`

Comment: `df1.drop(pd.Timestamp(indexes),inplace=True)` ?

Comment: Or can you share the code which makes this dataset?

Comment: I have updated the question. I was thinking about converting it to `strftime ` such as `data1.drop(data1.index[indexes.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')], axis = 0,inplace =True)` but i am getting `IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer or boolean type` dont get it why?

Comment: If `Date` is the `level 1` index of your data so it should work..

Comment: I used : `data1[~data1.index.duplicated(keep='first')]` This worked thanks for you time!